# How to change "activity in window" color in byobu

Tags: statusbar, tmux, byobu

Given the following byobu (with tmux backend) status bar, how can the window activity notification colors be adjusted?  Since they are currently the same as the "active" window, it is difficult to tell the difference.

[image: status bar]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure!  You can set it like this, in your `~/.byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g window-status-activity-bg red
```

For a complete list of color options, refer to [tmux.1](http://manpg.es/tmux.1) and specifically its [`OPTIONS` section](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/utopic/en/man1/tmux.1.html#contenttoc8)

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Comment: Beautiful, and with a `tmux source-file .byobu/.tmux.conf` and I was off and running.

Comment: Dustin, on a related subject, can byobu be setup so that it alternates activity and silence colors? So as to monitor a window where a process is constantly running, only sometimes things happen, sometimes not. Am I making sense?